# Fail message setting up docker container

Tags: linux, docker, cuda

I am trying to set up a docker container on my linux 18.04 system with an nvidia/cuda image but i cant make it run.

When i enter
`sudo nvidia-docker run --rm nvidia/cuda nvidia-smi`

i get this error message:

`docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:430: container init caused \"process_linux.go:413: running prestart hook 1 caused \\\"error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: exec command: [/usr/bin/nvidia-container-cli --load-kmods configure --ldconfig=@/sbin/ldconfig.real --device=all --compute --utility --require=cuda>=10.1 brand=tesla,driver>=384,driver<385 brand=tesla,driver>=396,driver<397 brand=tesla,driver>=410,driver<411 --pid=6233 /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ea6973074bef1b81269d114cd1d0eb15c3b28cc9159bf5f39f88bed8b463f504/merged]\\\\nnvidia-container-cli: requirement error: unsatisfied condition: brand = tesla\\\\n\\\"\"": unknown.`

I hope you have any ideas because i don't understand this errormessage.

Thank you so much.
Knust